# Squid cross compile

Tags: compiling, gcc, c, cross-compilation, squid

I've been trying to cross compile the Squid 3.5.7 on ARM Cortex A8 (Linux). 
I downloaded it from http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.5/ 
I have arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and arm-linux-gnueabi-g++.

```
tar -zxvf squid-3.5.7.tar.gz
cd squid-3.5.7
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid
```

After ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid I have this Makefile:http://wklej.se/makefile

```
make all
make install
```

Next I copy folders /usr/local/squid and ~/squid-3.5.7 to SD card. 
When I try open ./squid -z from SD card on the board with ARM I have problem:

```
root@am335x:/# ls
bin       etc       lib       mnt       srv       usr
boot      findHelp  linuxrc   proc      sys       var
dev       home      media     sbin      tmp
root@am335x:/media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin# ls
squid
root@am335x:/media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin# ./squid -z
./squid: line 20: syntax error: ")" unexpected
root@am335x:/media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin# ./squid
./squid: line 20: syntax error: ")" unexpected
root@am335x:/media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin#
```

I don't know what to do :/

Comment: The `squid` executable that you are running is a shell script, check around line number 20 to see why it throws this error.

Comment: this problem there is because i have problem with cross compiling :/

Comment: I can't see the squid because it is after compilation so it is an executable file

Comment: Did you try to do a `cat squid`?

Comment: when I used a cat squid:                                                                                                        o[�U��}�Tw�Q0�*�W%��B�W_N�[�Us�L�W;
\�U��}�\�Wy�<\�U       ����Tv�Q|���WZc\�U��}�T5�Q0���Wy\�Us���W�U��}���WǞ���W͞�Uv���������ʛ?��W ��\/]�ٛ�����E����W
��U�U#8�T�T�����W�S]d]��U��T�
R &�"^�^�P���Z�A���%�h����;�+��r��W8�]�����������W�U�T1�A

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `squid` file you were running. Do `cat /media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin/squid`.

Comment: http://pl.tinypic.com/r/znvw4i/8

Comment: could you tell me what i should write after ./configure to configure for ARM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually cross-compiling; to cross-compile you need to tell `./configure` about your target architecture:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --host=arm-linux-gnueabi
```

You should then get Makefiles which use `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, and a resulting `squid` binary which is appropriate for your ARM device. (Assuming you have all the necessary libraries of course.)

Comment: checking for compiler variant... gcc
configure: inlining optimizations enabled: yes
checking for GNU atomic operations support... configure: error: in `.../squid-3.5.7':
configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: You probably need to provide a `CONFIG_SITE` file to `configure` then... See [the `autoconf` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Site-Defaults.html) for details.

Comment: where can I find the autoconf manual ??

Comment: I linked to it in my comment above...

Comment: ok, however i don't know what i must change to work it.

Comment: it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the configure.ac file, look up the atomic section, and replace the line

```
AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[
```

with

```
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[
```

You then need to run bootstrap.sh to recreate the configure script.

This should let you configure, but compilation/linking might fail because your toolchain may not, in fact, support __sync_xxx calls. In my situation, libatomic.so did not contain these calls. I then had to resort to manually editing the configure script to always respond "no" to the atomic check:

```
squid_cv_gnu_atomics=yes
```

to

```
squid_cv_gnu_atomics=no
```